# NSMutableArray is only storing one value. Using Parse to query for data

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

My code querys parse and attempts to store the values obtained from parse into arrays. The arrays are then displayed in a table view in a new view controller.
When I execute my code it should result in storing two values in each array. This array will then populate a table view. When I execute my code only the first user's info is stored into each array. Can anyone spot the problem in my code that is causing only the first value to be stored in each array.

```
-(IBAction)displayfriendinfo:(id)sender{
phoneNUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
firstNAMES =[NSMutableArray new];
lastNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
EMAILS = [NSMutableArray new];
combinedNAMES = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Initialize table data
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendsAssociation"];
//quesrys the class Friend asssociation to find when instances of "user" equal the
//logged in user's username
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:usernamecontrol];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);

        // Do something with the found objects
        ContactTableViewController *contacts = [[ContactTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
        contacts.user = usernamecontrol;
        contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.FIRSTNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.PHONENUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.LASTNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];

        contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = combinedNAMES;
        contacts.PHONENUMBERS = phoneNUMBERS;
        contacts.FIRSTNAMES = firstNAMES;
        contacts.LASTNAMES = lastNAMES;

        [self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];

        if (objects.count == 0) {
            //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Friends"
                                                            message:@"No Friends"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }
        //if there is only one number matching the query

        if (objects.count >=1) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSLog(@"%@", objects);

                NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSString *firstname = object[@"firstName"];
                NSString *lastname = object [@"lastName"];
                NSString *email = object [@"email"];

                NSString *combinedname = object[@"combinedName"];

                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
                NSLog(@"%@", combinedname);


                [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
                [firstNAMES addObject:firstname];
                [lastNAMES addObject:lastname];
                [EMAILS addObject:email];
                [combinedNAMES addObject:combinedname];

                NSLog(@"yajdfk;adjskfas;dlfkja;klsdfjkla;sdjfk;ladfs");
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedNAMES);
                NSLog(@"%@",phoneNUMBERS);
            }
            //if there is more than one phonenumber matching the query as
            //the user to input the friends username
            //instead
        }

        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }}];
```

}

Specifically here is the portion of my code that stores the values queried from parse into the arrays.

```
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSLog(@"%@", objects);                    

                NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSString *firstname = object[@"firstName"];
                NSString *lastname = object [@"lastName"];
                NSString *email = object [@"email"];

                NSString *combinedname = object[@"combinedName"];
                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
                NSLog(@"%@", combinedname);


                [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
                [firstNAMES addObject:firstname];
                [lastNAMES addObject:lastname];
                [EMAILS addObject:email];
                [combinedNAMES addObject:combinedname];

                NSLog(@"yajdfk;adjskfas;dlfkja;klsdfjkla;sdjfk;ladfs");
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedNAMES);
                NSLog(@"%@",phoneNUMBERS);
            }
```

In addition the NSLog(@"yajdfk;adjskfas;dlfkja;klsdfjkla;sdjfk;ladfs");
is never displayed. However, NSLog(@"%@", objects); displays both users info accurately.
Here is the output

```
2015-03-07 20:33:07.626 ContactKeeper[46067:3405123] Successfully retrieved 2 users.
2015-03-07 20:33:07.630 ContactKeeper[46067:3405123] (
    "<friendsAssociation: 0x7abafd30, objectId: pcBKXGfASi, localId: (null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x7ab7c740>\";\n    combinedName = \"lewis meyer\";\n    firstName = lewis;\n    friendUsername = Louis;\n    lastName = meyer;\n    phoneNumber = 5555228243;\n    user = David;\n}",
    "<friendsAssociation: 0x7aba3c70, objectId: y1ToExVLew, localId: (null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x7abb3020>\";\n    combinedName = \"John Apple\";\n    email = \"rotha@g.com\";\n    firstName = John;\n    friendUsername = John;\n    lastName = Apple;\n    phoneNumber = 7075551854;\n    user = David;\n}"
)
```

Comment: You clearly are mistaken.  In the above code, if the first NSLog occurs and there is no error then the remaining 5 NSLogs will occur.  You should print `objects.count`.

Comment: I do in the line NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count); this prints out the correct number of users

Comment: So what exactly *is* printed?  You claim that "yajdfk;adjskfas;dlfkja;klsdfjkla;sdjfk;ladfs" *never* prints, which seems quite unbelievable if the code is not crashing.

Comment: So the code is crashing when you attempt to treat those strings as NSDictionarys.

Comment: the code never crashes, as far as I can tell, However  when the tableview loads it displays the NSMutable Array COMBINEDNAMES, but only displays lewis meyer and doesn't display John Apple.

Comment: Calling `[self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];` on a background thread (which it will be since you are in a block completion handler from `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`) is a recipe for fail

Comment: Trust me -- that code processing that array will fail.  If you're displaying Lewis Meyer it's because the data was there from earlier.

Comment: Where would you recommend I call this instead?

Comment: You need to  present the new view controller once you have finished loading the data rather than before - ie. at the end of the block.  You also need to dispatch this on the main queue

Comment: I changed the data on parse and got it to display the new data entered, but once again it only displayed the first occurrence and not the second. If it is in fact crashing how can I change it to get it to work?

Comment: @Paulw11, I don't think what you're saying about the thread is correct. I'm pretty sure that all Parse completion blocks run on the main thread.

Comment: Maybe - the documentation doesn't state, but it could be documented elsewhere.  The OP can try it without and see what happens. Either way, presenting the new view controller before adding all the data to the array is not going to work.

Comment: @Paulw11 where could I place this instead?

Comment: You could not possibly be displaying the data for Lewis Meyer from that block of code without executing the NSLog statements in that block of code.  And you could not be extracting any data from the two NSStrings in the array without somehow processing them first.

Comment: The array you are logging is an array of the `description` of two `friendsAssociation` objects, not two objects themselves.

Comment: @HotLicks see, I thought that too at first, but I found the code I am using to extract the data from the objects from Parse's documentation. And I agree with the statements regarding the NSLog I do not understand why they are not all executing.

Comment: Add an NSLog of your `objects` array right after you log the count.  And then add code there to iterate through the array and log the `.class` of each element.  Add the same log of `.class` in your loop.

Comment: @HotLicks The NSLog of objects returns the same information as presented in the question.     The NSLog of objects.class returns   2015-03-07 22:12:52.707 ContactKeeper[46706:3448632] __NSArrayM             The NSLog of object.class returns PFObject

Comment: So PFObject implements a `description` method that produces something looking like an NSString?  That kinda sucks.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I'm not sure if you are knowledgeable in this, but objects is a pointer and object is the PFObject is that correct?

Comment: That's what it would indicate.  The PFObject presumably contains that data internally.

Comment: @HotLicks Could it be something with the structure of the for loop? The NSLog's and so forth seem to indicate that the for loop is not completeing and is only doing like one loop instead of two.

Comment: "Only doing one loop instead of two" and also not doing those NSLogs makes no sense.  If you do `addObject` to `phoneNUMBERS` you should have NSLogged `phonenumber`.  (BTW, you should add text to each of your NSLogs so you can tell them apart.  I suspect that may be part of your problem -- that what you think is being logged at point A is really from the log at point B (which is indistinguishable).)

Comment: I'm still guessing that you're taking an exception.  It may be "handled" by `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`, so it doesn't take down the entire app.

Comment: I believe you are right, I have as far as I can tell determined that the code stops executing correctly when it gets to the the                               [EMAILS addObject:email;]  I added in NSLogs after each add object and the NSLog right after the emails add object does not execute.

Comment: @HotLicks I determined the Error. One of my parse objects did not have an email listed in the parse database so that must have messed up the add object portion. Once I added an email to this object the code executed as expected. Thank you so much for your help. However, I have a new question. Would you be able to instruct me on how to deal with instances where the object is blank and has no value in parse?

Comment: Presumably you could simply check `if (email != nil) { [EMAILS addObject:email]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my code was failing to execute correctly is because one of the values in my parse database from which I was querying from was a null value. This caused an exemption to be thrown. The updated code that I am now using which allowed me to work around the null parameter is as follows.

```
-(IBAction)displayfriendinfo:(id)sender{
phoneNUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
firstNAMES =[NSMutableArray new];
lastNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
EMAILS = [NSMutableArray new];
combinedNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
// Initialize table data
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendsAssociation"];
//quesrys the class Friend asssociation to find when instances of "user" equal the
//logged in user's username
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:usernamecontrol];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        NSLog(@"%@", objects.class);
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);


        // Do something with the found objects
        ContactTableViewController *contacts = [[ContactTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
        contacts.user = usernamecontrol;
        contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.FIRSTNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.PHONENUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.LASTNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];

        contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = combinedNAMES;
        contacts.PHONENUMBERS = phoneNUMBERS;
        contacts.FIRSTNAMES = firstNAMES;
        contacts.LASTNAMES = lastNAMES;

        [self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];

        if (objects.count == 0) {
            //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Friends"
                                                            message:@"No Friends"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];








        }
        //if there is only one number matching the query

        if (objects.count >=1) {
            NSLog(@"yajdfk;adjskfas;dlfkja;klsdfjkla;sdjfk;ladfs");



            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

               // NSLog(@"%@", objects);
           // NSLog(@"%@", object.class);

               NSDictionary *pn = object[@"phoneNumber"];
               NSDictionary *fn = object[@"firstName"];
               NSDictionary *ln= object [@"lastName"];
               NSDictionary *em = object [@"email"];

               NSDictionary *cm = object[@"combinedName"];






                NSLog(@"phonenumber %@", pn);
                NSLog(@"combined name%@", cm);

                if  (pn != NULL){
                    [phoneNUMBERS addObject:pn];
                    NSLog(@"number: %@",phoneNUMBERS);
                }
                if (fn != NULL) {
                    [firstNAMES addObject:fn];
                    NSLog(@"firstnaem: %@",firstNAMES);
                }
                if (ln !=NULL){
                    [lastNAMES addObject:ln];
                    NSLog(@"lastname: %@", lastNAMES);
                }

                if (em!=NULL) {
                    [EMAILS addObject:em];
                    NSLog(@"Email: %@", EMAILS);
                }
                if (cm != NULL) {
                    [combinedNAMES addObject:cm];


                    NSLog(@"combined names: %@",combinedNAMES);
                }



            }















        }

        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }}];
```